# T-SQL - Filtering records based on a date

Tags: sql, t-sql, filtering

I am writing SQL Server queries and need a solution for how to filter the rows that are returned properly.

The basic setup is as follows - I am selecting a bunch of records from a table based primarily on an identifier.  So, for a given identifier there might be 100 records that are returned initially.  Within these 100 records, however, there are a number of them that need to be deleted - not because they are duplicates, but because one is newer than the other.  So I essentially just need a way to further filter the results based on whichever record was created/modified most recently.

I know that ideally, these "old" records should not be in the database, but I don't have control over that.  What is happening is essentially people are updating the entries over time to reflect new information, but rather than editing the "old" entry, a new one gets entered each time.  Thus, there might be 3 entries for a given identifier, but I only need the one that was most recently entered.

Is there an easy way to do this in the T-SQL query string?  It would be similar to the "Last of" function in Access queries.  I do have a properly formatted date column for each record.

Thanks!

My query string so far (excuse the VB syntax):

```
    "SELECT *" & _
    "FROM Performance_Override " & _
    "WHERE ([Deal_Name] = " & "'" & Range("ID").value & "'" & " or" & _
    " [UNIQUE_ID] LIKE " & "'" & "%SPLIT_LOAN%" & "')" & " AND" & _
    " ([Scenario] = " & "'" & "BASE" & "')" & _
    "ORDER BY [Date] ASC; "
```

Comment: Do you mean like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: You could just select the max value of the DateTime column with that id and then do a statement deleting anything less than that date with the same id.

Comment: If you show us the query you have so far that can help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select is

```
select ID, max(datefield) 
from table 
group by ID
```

Do you just need a select or do you want to actually delete the old entries?

```
WITH TableTop AS
(
    SELECT ID, User, OrderDate
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ID BY OrderDate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Table
) 
SELECT ID, User, OrderDate  
FROM TableTop 
WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: That was easy!  Just the max function huh?  I only need to worry about the select, the database is going to keep the old entries.  One more question if you don't mind - I have about 70 fields in the database, do I now have to type them all out instead of using "SELECT *"?

Comment: Unfortunately * is not going to work.  But in SSMS just right click the table to create the select.

Comment: To follow-up - I am now getting an error that my other fields are not included in an aggregate function or the group by clause - so do I also need to type out all of the other fields in the group by clause as well?

Comment: Correct every field but the datefield.  Copy paste is your friend.

Comment: Alright - things are still not working properly (although I am clearly on the right track).  It seems to be including multiple dates for the same record to the extent that I include fields that are different among the two entries.  For example, if I just include the "ID" field (which is the same on both dates), then it properly filters out the older dates.  However, when I add an additional field, such as "Modifier" (the person who made the change/update on a subsequent date), then I am returning multiple records for a single ID (one for each unique ID-Date combo).  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I figured it out...so I used the "Max" function all of my terms that are not necessarily common across the different entries. Seems to have fixed the issue.  Please confirm if that makes sense - thanks again!

Comment: Then you should use RowNumber

Comment: No then you might not get the person associated with the max(dateField)

Comment: Sorry for the run-on discussion - so use RowNumber on each of the other (non-date) fields?  Could you post a simple example of how I would row number (along the lines of the modifier field listed above)?